# linux renames folders automatically

Tags: linux, server-message-block, cifs

I have a file server with ubuntu installed

It is accessed usually through smb either from pc (ubuntu) or laptop (windows 7)

Sometimes it happens that folder names on the file server are changing to some meaningless name, like `TOZC0N~L` or `TOJNL7~U`

The hard disks seem to be fine, and I can´t imagine that samba is messing up folder names.

There is no rule really for this problem and I can´t reproduce it, it just happens sometimes. Any ideas?

Here's fstab

```
#TREKSTORE 1TB
UUID=581C906F1C9049C0 /media/mext_2 ntfs defaults 0 0
#mext_3
UUID=4A466C6654E92192  /media/mext_4 ntfs defaults 0 0
#mext_2
UUID=EAB26EE9B26EB9A9 /media/mext_3 ntfs defaults 0 0

#Here's samba conf for one parititon
[mext_2]
comment = Public Folder
path = /media/mext_2
available = yes
public = yes
valid users = elmasry
read only = no
browsable = yes
writable = yes
```

Its the same for other hard disks

Comment: @MoatazElmasry You need to provide more info. What is the full path of these directories? When are they changing (after reboot, while running, etc)?

Comment: Are the folder names actually changing, as in you see that name on the file server, or is that just what Windows shows you?

Comment: can you post the original folder names and tell me whether the files have the correct names as the originals. Really it would be handy to see your /etc/fstab, your smb.conf, the output of `stat TOZC0N~L` and even the output of ls -lah TOZC0N~L

Comment: I added fstab smb confs. The I can't post the rest since I altered the names back to the original

Answer (score 3):

Update: It was suggested to try the following fix - add these lines to smb.conf;

```
dos charset = 1255
unix charset = UTF-8
display charset = UTF-8
```

paste the output of this command;

`[root@server-64634 ~]# testparm -s -v | grep "charset"

Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf

rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)

Processing section "[homes]"

Processing section "[printers]"

Loaded services file OK.

Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

        dos charset = CP850

        unix charset = UTF-8

        display charset = LOCALE`

---

It kind of looks likes you might be seeing some old school dos naming to [8.3 style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) name conversions, or even [iso 9660](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660#File_and_directory_name_restrictions)

Is any truly old school app opening and closing the files, or alternatively might be mounting the filesystem using some odd mount options that generates these converted names.

paste your /etc/fstab and your samba configuration for the client and server, showing your mounting and export options.

Comment: This was my first thought, but the 8.3 naming scheme is `123456~1` ... `123456~9` - also, `TOZC0N` could be the start of a real folder name, but it would be a weirdly named folder.

Comment: @MarkHenderson well i think this question is going to need a bunch of pasted outputs to make any more progress.

Comment: I have a strong feeling this question is going to be abandoned since it was migrated, so I wouldn't get your hopes up. But yes, I agree.

Comment: @MarkHenderson damn because it is quite interesting ;-)

Comment: I added the fstab and smb confs up there. maybe the names are too long, (>256) but as said no rule, sometimes it happens, I alter the folder names back to original, this time they don't get renamed

Comment: you might want to paste the output of this command ; `testparm -s -v | grep "charset"`

Answer (score 0):

Really just a shot in the dark but... Since you said a Windows box is accessing the samba share is there maybe a virus on the windows box that is messing with things?

Maybe run an antivirus on the windows box and then run clamav on the ubuntu file server and see if something comes up.

Again, just a shot in the dark.

Comment: thnx for the reply, thought about it as well, but windows machine has been scanned. no virus and no weird behaviour :( sadly

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this occur in a couple of scenarios, but only from the point of view of the Windows computer viewing the files over CIFS:

- The full path name of the file is ridiculously long, approaching or exceeding 256 characters
- The file name contains some character that is not valid on FAT or NTFS, such as an asterisk, backslash, or colon

In both cases, the only solution I've found is to rename the file to something appropriate for Windows to handle

Comment: this could be the case actually, but would windows alter the names immediatly after opening a mounted drive or upon accessing the the folder? because I certainly didn't access some of these folders recently, as I said its a weird behaviour and I can't reproduce this problem

Comment: I've never seen Windows actually rename the files in these cases, just appear to have the wrong name. I do see it sporadically as well, sometimes displaying the name correctly, some times not (same file).